# How to disable mouse click on Pause menu?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the new input system on my game so users can either use the keyboard and the mouse or a gamepad. However, I'm facing an issue with the pause menu. Whenever the game is paused and I press anywhere on the screen using the mouse, the selected option from the pause menu becomes unselected and I can't choose/click on any option anymore.
Here is the pause menu before the mouse click.
[image]
Here is what happens after the mouse click
[image]

```cs
private void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}
void Update()
{
    var gamepad = Gamepad.current;
    var keyboard = Keyboard.current;
    if (gamepad == null && keyboard == null)
        return; // No gamepad connected.
    if ((gamepad != null && gamepad.startButton.wasPressedThisFrame) || (keyboard !=null && keyboard.pKey.wasPressedThisFrame))
    {
        if (GameIsPaused)
        {
            Resume();

        }
        else
        {
            Pause();
        }
    }
}
public void Resume()
{
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameIsPaused = false;
}

private void Pause()
{
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameIsPaused = true;
}
```

even though the mouse isn't visible, I can still click anywhere on the screen and the click causes a bug that I can't choose from the menu anymore. How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

I found a really simple solution to this issue, in the new input system just unchecking this box fixes it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of controlling it is to have a singleton class that controls the state.

Have a state/game manager script with different game states

Create a new `GameState` enum.

```csharp
public enum GameSate
{
    NotSet,
    MainMenu,
    Playing,
    Paused,
}
```

Create a StateManager or GameManager class that will control the game state

```csharp
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameSate gameState = GameSate.NotSet;
    
    // Make it a singleton
    public state GameManager Instance { get; private set; }
    
    private void Awake() 
    { 
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this) Destroy(this); 
        else Instance = this;
    }
    
    // Give it event that other classes subscribed to
    public event EventHandler<GameSate> GameStateChangedEvent;
    
    public void InMainMenu()
    {
        gameState = GameSate.MainMenu;
        GameStateChangedEvent?.Invoke(gameState);
    }
    
    public void PlayGame()
    {
        gameState = GameSate.Playing;
        GameStateChangedEvent?.Invoke(gameState);
    }
    
    public void PauseGame()
    {
        gameState = GameSate.Paused;
        GameStateChangedEvent?.Invoke(gameState);
    }
}
```

Now inside any classes that listens for inputs do the following

```csharp
public class CharacterController 
{
    // Handle the game state change
    GameSate gameState;
    
    void Start() => GameManager.Instance.GameStateChangedEvent += ChangeState;
    
    void ChangeState(object sender, GameSate gameState) => this.gameState = gameState;
    
    // use the game state to pause
    void Update()
    {
        if (gameState == GameSate.Paused)
            return;
            
        ...
    }
}
```

If you have an input controller class you can change the state from that:

```csharp
public class InputController
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Esc))
        {
            PauseGame();
        }
    }
    
    public void PauseGame() => GameManager.Instance.PauseGame();        
    public void PlayGame() => GameManager.Instance.PauseGame();
    
}
```

---

### OPTION 2

Use a boolean to check if your game is paused or not.

```csharp
bool isPaused = false;

void Update()
{

    // Pauses the game and opens the menu
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Esc))
    {
        isPaused = !isPaused;
        ... Code To Show Menu ...
    }
    
    if (isPaused)
        return;
        
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(Input.Mouse0))
    {
        ... Handle Clicks ....
    }
}
```

Comment: So adding this would stop the mouse clicks? where exactly should I add the enum GameSate?

Comment: @Okashi I added an Option two that might be a bit easier to do.

Comment: I don't want the mouse clicks in my entire game. only gamepad and keyboard arrows.

Comment: Then just delete the mouse click code.